# Office.context.mailbox.item.getEntities() returns null for all entities

Tags: outlook, outlook-web-addins

I followed the sample code that is shared at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/extract-entity-strings-from-an-item#extracting-task-suggestions. I have an email, that has a valid address (1234 Main Street, Redmond, WA 07722). But all the entities on the email are null, including the 'Addresses' entity.

> Return value for Office.context.mailbox.item.getEntities():

`{ "_data$p$0": { "Addresses": null, "Contacts": null, "EmailAddresses": null, "MeetingSuggestions": null, "PhoneNumbers": null, "TaskSuggestions": null, "Urls": null }, "_filteredData$p$0": {}, "_dateTimeSent$p$0": "2019-11-15T12:01:19.000Z", "_permissionLevel$p$0": 2, "_addresses$p$0": [] }`

Any help to get it to work will be greatly appreciated.

Regards
~Surjya.

Comment: Update: It detects urls in the message body. But other entities are empty. Perhaps, the text is my message body does not match a valid address/phone number/task. It will be really helpful if I can get sample texts for any of the above entity types.

Comment: Thanks for writing to us. We are looking into this and we will get back to you.

Comment: Sorry for delay in responding. We could verify that address entity is fetched using following code. Please refer to documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.5/office.context.mailbox.item#getentities--entities



var addresses = item.getEntitiesByType(Office.MailboxEnums.EntityType.Address);

Comment: Could you please suggest what specific word or group of words in the message body would qualify as a TaskSuggestion entity? I have the following text in the message body, which does not get identified as a TaskSuggestion entity:

`@Valid Domain User, could you please take a look?`